# Adding Subscribe Button for a RSS URL

Tags: asp.net, rss, rss-reader

I have a RSS URL for my website and i have to make people directly subscribe this URL clicking on a image from my home page. The image click must have the functionality similar to "Subscribe" button which is found in the header of the RSS Page.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare your RSS as HTML links ([How To Tell Web Browsers About Atom Feeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440391/how-to-tell-web-browsers-about-atom-feeds)) then many browsers will show 'Subscribe' buttons. However, there's no general way to cause subscription with a single link; you're better off linking to the feed and relying on the browser to offer to add a new subscription.

(You may be able to do better with some specific aggregators, but I'm assuming you're after something using your browser's subscription mechanism here.)

Comment: Im actually looking to add a icon in my page which allows to subscribe directly

Comment: You may get somewhere with a variant of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992844/add-to-browser-favorites-bookmarks-from-javascript-but-for-all-browsers-mine-do, but I don't think you'll find a reliable, general solution.